# Changing the character encoding of a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, encoding, charset

Our whole application is now able to handle UTF-8 and it will be our choice in terms of encoding all across our architecture. The last step is to change the encoding of our MySQL databases.

Of course, `ALTER TABLE db_table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;` should be able to convert each of the tables to the right UTF8 encoding, yet, is there anything else I should do? I believe that the my.cnf configuration file needs to be changed as well.

Comment: Shouldn't you be enjoying Christmas Day, instead of posting here?

Comment: Shouldn't you be enjoying Xmas, instead of commenting? :D Not everyone celebrates Xmas!

Comment: I don't enjoy christmas.  My iphone's decided to break finally today. Best Xmas Ever (!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy and paste this into a terminal and restart the Mysql server to change the default character encoding.

```
cat << EOF > /etc/mysql/conf.d/utf8.cnf

[mysqld]
default-character-set=utf8

[client]
default-character-set=utf8

EOF
```

Comment: ha, thx... that's a good one.

Answer (score 0):

You should also set the character-set from your client application by these sql statements:

```
SET character_set_client = utf8;
SET character_set_results = utf8;
SET character_set_connection = utf8;
```